# Android Materil Slider. No label

Tags: android, slider

I just included very last material library in my project `com.google.android.material:material:1.3.0-alpha02`. Then I implemented it in layout

```
    <LinearLayout
        android:id="@+id/animation_speed"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:divider="@drawable/divider_4dp"
        android:orientation="vertical"
        android:showDividers="middle">

        <com.google.android.material.textview.MaterialTextView
            android:id="@+id/speed_label"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginStart="8dp"
            android:text="Скорость анимации" />

        <com.google.android.material.slider.Slider
            android:id="@+id/slider"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_gravity="center"
            android:valueFrom="100.0"
            android:valueTo="100000.0" />
    </LinearLayout>
```

Also, there is my code for label's formatter:

```
    engine_settings.slider.setLabelFormatter { "Text" }
```

Then I run my project. But when I started to slide the slider, I noticed, that there is no label. I want to see label above slider. How to display it?

P.S.

My application theme is inherited from `MaterialBaseBaseTheme`

Also, I tried to downgrade material library to 1.2.0-alpha5 and others, but no result.

Comment: What is `MaterialBaseBaseTheme` ? the code works.

Comment: @GabrieleMariotti `MaterialBaseBaseTheme` is theme from library `materialize` by MikePenz

Comment: I am not able to reproduce the bug. The label works fine.

Comment: @GabrieleMariotti I found the reason of my bug just now. In my `AndroidManifest.xml` file was string  `android:hardwareAccelerated="false"`. Once I removed it, label has arrived.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found the reason of my bug just now. In my `AndroidManifest.xml` file was string  `android:hardwareAccelerated="false"`. Once I removed it, label has arrived.

Comment: com.google.android.material:material:1.4.0 had the same issue. Removing android:hardwareAccelerated="false" did the trick, thanks!